# не работает роутинг laravel 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker, docker-compose

При создании любого роута выдается 404 ошибка (даже на пустом проекте)

nginx:

```
server {

index index.html index.php;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/public;

index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_pass app:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');});

Route::get('/greeting', function () {
return 'Hello World';});
```

Comment: Где server_name? Где listen [port]? nginx -t покажет ошибки, скорее всего